# Unable to pass reference from one class to another

Tags: c++, linux, constructor, reference

I'm writing a C++ program intended to manage the resources and duties in a flat.
This program is intended to run in Linux Shell.

I created a class call HomePage for users to login. I've also got another class called SelectionPage. Which are the Menus after the user got past the login. In my main functions, i wish to pass some data obtained by an instance of the HomePage class, to an instance of the SelectionPage class.

I've been stuck here for at least 6 hours, Could someone please help?

Here's the error message:

```
g++ C_Main.cpp C_HomePage.cpp C_SelectionPage.cpp -o Project
C_Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
C_Main.cpp:17:93: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >) ()’
C_Main.cpp:17:122: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >) ()’
C_HomePage.cpp:290:41: error: no ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > HomePage::getDutiesList()’ member function declared in class ‘HomePage’
C_HomePage.cpp:294:44: error: no ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > HomePage::getResourcesList()’ member function declared in class ‘HomePage’
C_SelectionPage.cpp:9:144: error: declaration of ‘SelectionPage::SelectionPage(std::string, int, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::string)’ outside of class is not definition
C_SelectionPage.cpp:9:146: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
make: *** [Project] Error 1
```

Here is my main()

```
// Testing Home Page Functionality
#include "H_HomePage.h"
#include "H_SelectionPage.h"

using namespace std;

string initializationFile = "D_initialization.dat";
string flatMemberFile = "D_flatMember.dat";

    int main()
       {
        HomePage frontEnd(initializationFile);             //Create Boundary Object
        system("clear");                                //Clear Terminal Screen
        frontEnd.login(flatMemberFile);

    SelectionPage Menu(frontEnd.getManager(), frontEnd.getInitPoints(), frontEnd.getDutiesList(), frontEnd.getResourcesList(), frontEnd.getLoginName());
      Menu.showManagerMenu();
        return 0;
       }
```

Here's my constructor for SelectionPage class, as described in the header file:

```
...
SelectionPage(string Manager, int Points, vector <string> dutiesList, vector <string> resourceList, string loginName);
...
```

Here's the implementation of the constructor for SelectionPage class:

```
    SelectionPage::SelectionPage(string newanager, int points, vector <string> newDutiesList, vector <string> newResourceList, string newLoginName);{
    manager = newManage;
    initPoints = points;
    dutiesList = newDutiesList;
    resourceList = newResourceList;
    loginName = newLoginName;
}
```

could someone please, please help? I'll be ever so grateful!

Comment: `string newLoginName);{` in that last code block looks very, very strange. Please post your real code and take a bit more care with the formatting. Also, without seeing your class declarations, it's a bit hard to guess what is wrong exactly.

Comment: `newanager` in your `SelectionPage` constructor? How did `manager = newManage;` not throw a compile error? What is on lines `C_Main.cpp:17`, `C_HomePage.cpp:290` and `294`, and `C_SelectionPage.cpp:9`?

Comment: ... and the error is probably somewhere else. Can you mark the lines where the compiler is throwing errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your error messages carefully.

```
C_HomePage.cpp:290:41: error: no ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > HomePage::getDutiesList()’ member function declared in class ‘HomePage’
C_HomePage.cpp:294:44: error: no ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > HomePage::getResourcesList()’ member function declared in class ‘HomePage’
```

You probably have incorrect declarations for `HomePage::getDutiesList()` and `HomePage::getResourcesList()`, or none at all. It's hard to tell what exactly is wrong with them without looking at the class declaration. This is also the reason of compiler errors in your `main()`.

The reason of the other two compiler errors is probably the spurious `;` between `)` and `{' in the definition of`SelectionPage::SelectionPage`. Get rid of it.